# Elasticsearch bulk update geo_location of all documents with curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of documents in Elasticsearch that don't have a geo_point attribute.
Now I want to add it to all of them.

With some research I found the command bellow but was originally used to update a string attribute.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/products/_update_by_query" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.location = {'lat': 0.0, 'lon':0.0}",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

Thought I'd just replace the string with geo_point but it gives me this error:

```
{
 "error":{
  "root_cause":[{
   "type":"parse_exception",
   "reason":"expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"
  }],
  "type":"parse_exception",
  "reason":"expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"
 },
 "status":400
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job so far!

It looks like you're running an older version of ES. Try the command below which simply replaces `source` by `inline` as it was the norm in older versions:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/products/_update_by_query" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.location = ['lat': 0.0, 'lon':0.0]",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

Note, however, that if your `location` field is already of type `text` or `string` you cannot change it to `geo_point` with this command. You'll need to either create a new field named differently than `location` and of type `geo_point` or create a new index with the proper mapping for the `location` field.

Edit: If the above doesn't work, try replacing single quote `'` with `\"` like so

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/products/_update_by_query" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.location = [\"lat\": 0.0, \"lon\":0.0]",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thank you @Val, It seems like that was the issue, however when I run it, it gives me this error
`
"root_cause": [
   {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "compile error",
    "script_stack": [
     "ctx._source.location = { lat: 0.0, lon:0.0 }",
     "                       ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "ctx._source.location = { lat: 0.0, lon:0.0 }",
    "lang": "painless"
   }
  ],
`

Comment: Awesome! I've updated the script, you need square brackets instead of curly braces. let me know how that goes.

Comment: Now it's saying "Variable [lat] is not defined."

Comment: Are you sure that `lat` is between single quotes like this `'lat'`? Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: I replaced ' with \" and It worked now. Thank you so much for your help.
The version is 5.5.2

Comment: Thanks, I updated your response to include the fix :)